# map strings to class members

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Say I have a class / struct like below:

```
struct A {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint16_t c;
};
```

And I have a set of strings that associate to each member of A (could be of different integer types, but not non-integer types such as strings), e.g.

```
"field1" -> A::a
"field2" -> A::b
"field3" -> A::c
```

Assume that there is always a 1:1 mapping between the strings and members. Is there an elegant way to map each string to each member using something like std::unordered_map? 
I want to be able to read and write to each field using the strings as keys, e.g.

```
A a {1,2,3};
mymap["field1"] = 4; // a.a = 4
mymap["field2"] = 5; // a.b = 5
auto c = mymap["field3"]; // c = a.c = 3
```

I'm using C++11/14 and can't use boost.

---

***Some more information on the context of this question***:
The `struct A` mentioned in the question are settings of the program. They are hardware configuration parameters and my software program is used to simulate hardware behaviours. These settings/configurations are script-generated `struct`s like above. We read / write these `struct` members and because the amount of these settings/configurations are so many (a few thousands), it would be convenient to be able to access them by their names as well. This is how & why I want to associate each member with a string. Whether it is subscripting or a function to access the corresponding members does not really matter, but there is such a 1:1 mapping between a string (name of the setting) and the generated `struct` member. And as I mentioned in the question, these members are of different integer types.

Comment: Are the strings "fieldN" compile-time constants or are they runtime. If it is the second then the basic problem is that the references are different types.

Comment: @alfC the keys such as "fieldN" are compile time constants.

Comment: If they were the same type you could use [pointers to data members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members), but that doesn't work with them being different types.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was voted to be closed for the reason of "unclear what you're asking" - whoever did that, do you care to tell me what is unclear?!

Comment: Well, you could use a `std::unordered_map`, but the value of the map must be a `std::variant` of all (member pointers to) possible datatypes that comprise the class, but `std::variant` is C++17. Perhaps you might want to try asking the real question. No, not the one about mapping strings to class members. This would be the real question to which you believe the answer must be "map strings to class members", so that's what you're asking about. Your real question will most likely have a different answer, but without knowing the real question, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik given the constraints of my code base and my understanding of the problem, I believe this IS the real question to find an answer to map strings to class members. Even if "map strings to class members" was not the "real question", what's the problem of asking such a question? Can't curiosity a good motivation to ask such a question?

Comment: Curiosity can be a motivator, but if you have a problem in a real code base and there is a better solution (e.g., make a struct where the members are references to the members of your `A` struct but with different names, or use an `assign(A a, std::string field)` function implemented with a stack of `if`s or something), taking a step back can help figure that out. Even just saying if some of the requirements are flexible can be useful, because the particular syntax you ask for would be hard to implement and would have maybe-unnecessary runtine costs.

Comment: @DanielH If there is a "real question" in my real code base and I really can tell what it is, I wouldn't hold it back. I have tried my best to simplify my situation and at the same time trying to describe the issue to the best of my understanding and knowledge. From the comments above, it seems like the answer to this question is simply  - No, there is no elegant/simple way to do it in C++11/14. Thanks, guys.

Comment: There's certainly no problem with asking this question. Except that you're not going to get a good answer, while it's likely that there's an excellent answer to the real question, but unless it's asked, the excellent answer will not be given. How can someone possibly give an excellent answer to a question that's not even asked?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand your point, but how can you be so sure this is not the real question?

Comment: the problem is, that all your members are of different types, which you have to use either for initialization or for return **dynamically**.  There is no *elegant* solution to this problem. Easy to do if all of them are of the same type though.

Comment: Because in the 20+ years of writing all possible kinds of C++ code, I've yet to find any need to do something like this. Even in one of my current projects, that involves implementing a serialization template, a'la boost, that also needs to go through all class members. There's always a better way to do whatever's being tried, here.

Comment: So the way to see if it is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) is sort of like being a stereotypical 2-year-old. Why do you want to do this? Why do you need strings and subscripting in particular? You say the strings you're using are compile-time constants, but is that true both of the values you accept (you know you want `"field1"` and `"field2"`) or also at the call site (I know when I write `mymap[str]` exactly what value `str` will have)?

Comment: SamVarshavchik and @DanielH I have added more context to my question. As I said earlier, I wouldn't hold it back if there is a different "real question" that I can tell.

Comment: Can you change the part of the code that does the generation? Are you willing to have more generated code for accessing these by name?

Comment: @Daniel H that depends on what to change. The structs have to stay as they are extensively used. I might be able to add some additional code to allow name based access. Our existing solution is to generate a string comparison for each configuration and return the corresponding struct member, which is so inefficient (thousands of string compares each time we access them by name!)

Comment: What I would do is generate a `class NamedA { private: A& innerA; public: NamedA(A& a) : innerA{A a}{} uint32_t& field1 = innerA.a; uint8_t& field2 = innerA.b; uint16_t& field3 = innerA.c; };` (Or similar; I haven't tested that this even compiles and you might want to change various details). This would be relatively easy to auto-generate and have a lot better runtime performance than anything string-based.

Comment: @DanielH this is like changing the variable names. The existing struct members all have meaningful variable names already. The point is to allow the user of the software to access these members more conveniently. Think about something similar to accessing Windows register book - each entry can be searched by its name.

Comment: So the strings are provided at runtime? I thought based on the strings you were using being different from the field names the auto-generated ones weren't meaningful.

Comment: The field names are generated compile time constants, but the search term used to find and access these fields are of course provided in run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a proxy-class that wraps around a integer, then store this proxy class in a `std::unordered_map`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

struct A {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint16_t c;
};

struct ValueWrapper {
    using value_type = uint64_t;

    template <typename Obj, typename T>
    ValueWrapper(Obj& obj, T Obj::*member) {
        get = [&, member]() { return obj.*member; };
        set = [&, member](value_type value) mutable { obj.*member = value; };
    }

    ValueWrapper()  = default;

    ValueWrapper& operator=(value_type value) {
        set(value);
        return *this;
    }

    operator value_type() {
        return get();
    }

    std::function<value_type()> get;
    std::function<void(value_type)> set;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, ValueWrapper> make_map(A& a) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ValueWrapper> map;

    map["field1"] = ValueWrapper(a, &A::a);
    map["field2"] = ValueWrapper(a, &A::b);
    map["field3"] = ValueWrapper(a, &A::c);

    return map;
}

int main() {
    A a{1,2,3};

    auto map = make_map(a);

    map["field2"] = 67;

    std::cout << a.a << " " << static_cast<int>(a.b) << " " << a.c << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  map["field1"] << " " <<  map["field2"] << " " <<  map["field3"] << std::endl;
}
```

You do get some restrictions depending on the `value_type`. If you use `int64_t` you could wrap anything but a `uint64_t` safely. If you go for a `uint64_t` you could wrap all the unsigned integers, but not the signed ones safely.

I put the default constructor there to satisfy `unordered_map`s use of `operator[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class V>
struct pseudo_ref_t {
  operator V()&& { return getter(); }
  void operator=(V v)&&{
    setter(std::move(v));
  }

  std::function<void(V)> setter;
  std::function<V()> getter;
};
template<class T, class V>
struct member_t {
  friend pseudo_ref_t<V> operator->*( T* t, member_t const& self ) {
    return {
      [&self, t](V in){ self.setter(*t, std::move(in)); },
      [&self, t]()->V{ return self.getter(*t); }
    };
  }
  friend V operator->*( T const* t, member_t const& self ) {
    return self.getter(*t);
  }
  std::function<void(T&, V)> setter;
  std::function<V(T const&)> getter;
};
template<class T, class V, class X>
member_t<T, V> make_member( X T::* mem_ptr ) {
  return {
    [mem_ptr](T& t, V in) {
      (t.*mem_ptr) = std::move(in);
    },
    [mem_ptr](T const& t)->V {
      return (t.*mem_ptr);
    }
  };
}
```

a `member_t<A, uint32_t>` can type-erase any member of `A` that implicitly convertible to/from a `uint32_t`.

It acts like a smart member pointer.

Answer (score 0):

you said that it could have different integer types, but it is a problem for having an elegant solution. If you can set up on a single type, this would be simple, like the following.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <map>

 struct A {
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;
 };
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
     map<string, int A::*> abc = {
         {"a", &A::a},
         {"b", &A::b},
         {"c", &A::c}
     };

     A aa;

     aa.*abc["a"] = 1;
     aa.*abc["b"] = 2;
     aa.*abc["c"] = 3;

     cout << "a = " << aa.a << "(" << aa.*abc["a"] << ")" << endl;
     cout << "b = " << aa.b << "(" << aa.*abc["b"] << ")" << endl;
     cout << "c = " << aa.c << "(" << aa.*abc["c"] << ")" << endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Yes agree, if I could have them all in the same type then I would have done the same as you suggested. Unfortunately I have to keep them different types as they are because they are script generated data types and I don’t want to use a bigger integer type if a small integer type is enough.

Comment: Then you are bound to the bunch of cast operations at minimum, and you have to know the type of every field at the time of casting. It is dynamic, done at run time. All type manipulations with templates are compile-time. Therefore there is no elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge of your question is that different members have different types. 
If you make the types the same, you can use a lot of tricks.

For your case, I know you don't want to use Boost or C++17, but just to show you the challenges ahead, let me give you a Boost.Hana, C++17 solution.

```
#define  BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/string.hpp>
#include <cstdint> // uint
#include <cassert>

struct A {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint16_t c;
};

struct map{
    A& aa_;
    template<class String>
    decltype(auto) operator[](String s) const{
        using namespace boost::hana::literals;
        if constexpr(s == "field1"_s) return (decltype(aa_.a)&)(aa_.a);
        if constexpr(s == "field2"_s) return (decltype(aa_.b)&)(aa_.b);
        if constexpr(s == "field3"_s) return (decltype(aa_.c)&)(aa_.c);
    }
};

using namespace boost::hana::literals;

void f(uint32_t& a){ a = 3.;}

int main(){
    A aa{1,2,3};
    map mymap{aa};
    mymap["field1"_s] = 4; assert(aa.a == 4);
    mymap["field2"_s] = 5; assert(aa.b == 5);
    mymap["field3"_s] = 6; assert(aa.c == 6);
    auto c = mymap["field3"_s]; assert( c == aa.c );
    mymap["blabla"_s]; // is void (not a compile error)
    assert( map{aa}["field1"_s] == 4 );
}
```

From this you can walk backwards and perhaps figure out a C++14, the challenge ahead is that you have to implement your own compile time string literals and equality.
In other words, reimplement your own Hana string strings: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/namespaceboost_1_1hana_1_1literals.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is that if you have a script that can generate the struct then you can have your script **generate** your setters.

Start with a simple function interface.

```
struct A {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint16_t c;
};

typedef std::function<void(A &,string)> SetterType
```

Then create a lookup table

```
std::map<std::string,SetterType> Lookup;
```

and for each field, using your script, generate a parser and setter;

```
void A_a(A & data, std::string input){
        data.a = std::stoi(input);
}
```

and then

```
Lookup["a"] = &A_a;
```

and use it like

```
Lookup["a"]("10");
```

If you can't modify the generating script then maybe you can use a third party parser such as [swig](http://www.swig.org/compare.html) or [clang](http://szelei.me/code-generator/) to read your structures and generate you a parse tree that you can then use to generate your lookup tables.

Or just use a system that already maps strings to C++. A C++ JSON generator.

https://nlohmann.github.io/json/